# Getting the path of items on your network

Tags: linux, backup, readynas

I have a ReadyNAS on my network that I can't SSH or rsync into because it doesn't allow connections on port 22. I can, however, see the machine in Ubuntu's filesystem GUI under "Network". If I open up the ReadyNAS's folder there, I can see all the files I'm interested in.

How can I get to these files from the command line so that I might copy them via a `cp` command? I already tried `sudo find / -name 'filename'` and nothing turned up.

My overall goal is to copy the files from the ReadyNAS onto my Linux box via a script.

Edit: I found what may be a clue. My share is called `gob` and my ReadyNAS is called Galapagos_NAS and I found the following files in my home folder:

```
/home/jason/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/smb-share:server=galapagosnas.local,share=gob
/home/jason/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/smb-share:server=galapagosnas.local,share=gob-4f3182b8.log
```

Also, the ReadyNAS documentation says that to connect to the ReadyNAS from Linux, you can do this:

```
mount <ipaddr>:/<backup /backup>
```

where `backup` is the share name which, in my case is `gob`. According to the instructions, I should be able to do

```
sudo mount 192.168.140.2:/gob /gob
```

But I get an error: mount: `mount point /gob does not exist`. I don't know why this is or how to try to fix it.

Edit 2: I created a directory /home/jason/gob and now I'm running this command:

```
sudo mount 192.168.140.2:/gob /home/jason/gob/
```

And getting this error:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on 192.168.140.2:/gob,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       (for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might
       need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program)
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

And here's this:

```
$ dmesg | tail
[   20.816764] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[   22.675899] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro,commit=0
[   28.384106] eth1: no IPv6 routers present
[   29.658406] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro,commit=0
[   31.736021] eth0: no IPv6 routers present
[   99.689403] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[   99.689408] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[   99.689410] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[   99.807517] FS-Cache: Loaded
[   99.891512] FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
```

I don't know what to do next.

Comment: You do have a local directory /gob, don't you?

Comment: No, I don't. Apparently I should?

Comment: Yes, the "mount point" refers to an existing directory where you want the filesystem mounted, so you need to create an empty directory for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your NAS box is clearly sharing using one protocol or another - probably CIFS/SMB - so try mounting the box that way, it might be NFS or FTP but I'd start via CIFS/SMB first.

Comment: Yes, it's sharing using CIFS. As for "mounting the box that way," can you really spell it out for me? I'm new to this. Thanks.

Comment: mount.cifs //*IP-address*/*mount-name* /mnt/*mount-point* -o username=*userID*,password=*password*,domain=*domain*

Comment: Hmm, I don't think it needs or wants a username/password. If you look at my edit on my question, the `mount` command in the ReadyNAS documentation doesn't use one. If I take the username part out of your command, I still get the same error as when I try the command from the ReadyNAS docs.

Comment: The fix was a variation of your answer: `sudo mount.cifs 192.168.140.2:/gob /home/jason/gob/` after creating /home/jason/gob.

Comment: Yeah sorry, you need to create the mount point first.